# How to debug stored procedures in an environment where Visual Studio user has limited rights?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've read the Visual Studio 2010 documentation that says that it is possible to attach a debugger and step thru a stored procedure the same way I can step thru .net or JavaScript code in Visual Studio 2010.

However, when I try to do this, I see the error message: `User 'dbo' could not execute stored procedure 'master.dbo.sp_enable_sql_debug' on SQL Server XXXXXXXXXX`.

I spoke with my DBA regarding this issue.  He says that there is no way of allowing debugging without making the developers admin users, which is a non-starter in the environment in which I work.

The first work-around that comes to mind would be to install SQL Server Express on the developers' workstations, but this is also not allowed; it is absolutely verboten by the powers that be.

I realize that this seems like an arbitrary situation, and it a way, it is.

I would like to ask if there is some way to enable SQL debugging without making the developers admin users and without having any database server running on development workstations.

As an aside, I am not a DBA.  My DBA says that he doesn't know much about Visual Studio, so I wouldn't be surprised if there is some obvious solution we've overlooked.  Our SQL server is MS SQL.

Comment: If they won't let you have the tools you need to do your work, there's not much you can do.

Comment: @Jim, we work at an organization that has (seemingly arbitrary) rules about how we do our job.  My question is whether or not it is possible to work within those rules to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to explicitly `debug` a stored procedure? In the old days, we did things like `PRINT` and `RAISERROR` to "debug." I know it sounds really hard but those methods still work today.

Comment: When it's someone else's stored procedure that I don't have permission to modify, yes, it is really hard.

Comment: If you can *read* the text of the stored procedure, then you could make a copy of it and do whatever you want to it... the *only* answer here can't be "we absolutely must be able to use the debug functionality inside Visual Studio."

Comment: That would be the preferrable answer :-)